# Create a database with username and password in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How to create a database with username and password in Java?

I created a DB using

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", USER, PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE "+DB_NAME;);
    // DB creatd
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but now if I connect to this database using:

```
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+DBNAME,user,pass);
```

what should I enter in the use and pass?
And more importantly how do I create a DB with properties?

Comment: You should first create the Mysql database, and jdbc is only used to connect your java application with this database. So be sure that the database DBNAME already exist and that you use the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to have very good reason to create a database via code but You would enter the same login credential as the one that created the database:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+DBNAME, USER, PASS);
```

Alternatively once connected to the server you can connect to the database by running following query:

```
USE DB_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Connection conn1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/",user,pass);
  stmt = conn1.createStatement();
  String sql = "CREATE DATABASE UTSAV";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```